# Complete Solution to Damped Pendulum Second-Order Differential

Tags: friction, oscillators, differential-equations

Of all the pages I've read on this stack exchange, I've seen numerous proofs and comments on the complete solution to the period of an undamped pendulum, and they all involve complete elliptic integrals of the first kind. They all start with $\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{mgL}{I}sin(\theta)$, and end up at:

$$T=4\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2sin^2(\theta)}}d\theta$$

But I can't seem to find anything on the entire internet for the solution to the differential equation for damped oscillators:
$$\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{L}{I}(mgsin(\theta)+b\dot{\theta})$$
$$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{bL}{I}\dot\theta+\frac{mgL}{I}sin(\theta)=0$$

**EDIT: I am looking for a solution that does not make the small angle approximation of $sin(\theta)\approx\theta$. Sorry for any inconvenience!**

Does anyone have any solution? I haven't taken complex analysis and have a very surface-level understanding of elliptic integrals, but I'm very curious about the answer...

Comment: The reason we can solve the simple pendulum equation is that it has a conserved quantity, namely the total energy. Since the energy of the damped pendulum is not conserved, my guess would be that we cannot solve it exactly, but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

We can write solution easily by considering small angle approximation, $\sin\theta =\theta$
So, the differential equation becomes,
$\ddot\theta + \frac{bL}{I}\dot\theta+\frac{mgL}{I}\theta = 0\tag{1}$
Now we can see that it is a differential equation with constant coefficients.
So, we can assume that solution might be $e^{\lambda t}$. Because then if we take derivatives of exponential function the coeffecient of $t$ in the exponent (which is a constant) comes in front of it.
So, plugging $\theta = e^{\lambda t}$ in $(1)$ we get
$(\lambda^2+\frac{bL}{I}\lambda+\frac{mgL}{I})e^{\lambda t} = 0$
As the above equation should hold $\forall t$. But $e^{\lambda t}\neq 0$ for any $t$.
So, $\lambda^2+\frac{bL}{I}\lambda+\frac{mgL}{I}=0$
We get a quadratic equation in $\lambda$.
Put $\gamma = \frac{bL}{I}$ (damping constant) and $\omega_o^2 = \frac{mgL}{I}$
$\lambda = \frac{-\gamma\pm\sqrt{\gamma^2-4\omega_o^2}}{2}$

Now we can get different solutions depending on the damping conditions.
**i) Underdamped ($\gamma^2<4\omega_o^2$)**
$\lambda = \frac{-\gamma\pm i\sqrt{\gamma^2-4\omega_o^2}}{2}$

Put $\frac{(\gamma^2-4\omega_o^2)}{4} = \omega^2$
We get $\lambda = -\frac{\gamma}{2}\pm i\omega$
So, $x(t)=e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}}(c_1e^{i\omega t}+c_2e^{-i\omega t})$
We can also write $x(t)=e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}}(c_1'\cos\omega t+c_2'\sin\omega t)$

Similarly we can write solution for critically damped and overdamped conditions

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I think I miscommunicated what I was looking for. By "complete" solution, I meant a solution that does not make the small angle approximation. Once again, I did not communicate this correctly in my question. I apologize, and will edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

The second order non-linear differential equations are generally not solvable. The reason why we can solve it without damping is that we know the *first integral* of the equation (the energy), which allows reducing it to a first order one (see, e.g., [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/556778/247642) for the general technique.)